# Yii session management

Tags: php, session, yii

I am trying to set some session variable in Yii using the following code :

```
    $session=new CHttpSession;
            $session->open() ;
            $session->setSessionName('My Session') ; 
            $session['sleep'] = 0 ;
            $session['attempts'] = 0 ;
            $session->writeSession('sleep','0') ; 
            $session['ip'] = $this->get_ip_address() ; $session->close() ;    var_dump($session,$session['ip']) ;
```

However , I am not able to set the session vaiables above , the dump has the following result :

```
object(CHttpSession)#17 (5) { ["autoStart"]=> bool(true) ["behaviors"]=> array(0) { } ["_initialized":"CApplicationComponent":private]=> bool(false) ["_e":"CComponent":private]=> NULL ["_m":"CComponent":private]=> NULL } string(3) "::1"
```

It sees $session and $session['ip'] as two completely different variables . Can someone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I work with sessions under Yii in another way, I use the global session variable under the app() variable. So you can store values like this:

```
Yii::app()->session['sleep'] = "value";
```

And you can get values like this:

```
$sleep = Yii::app()->session['sleep'];
```

Finally you can remove it like this:

```
unset(Yii::app()->session['sleep']);
```

This way you can access them everywhere in your code. I recommend you to read this article: http://www.larryullman.com/2011/05/03/using-sessions-with-the-yii-framework/ it has all the information that you need.

Comment: Yeah , this is what I ended up doing !! Thanks for the answer anyways !!

Comment: I Use it too. But, what's difference between this and CHttpSession?

Comment: I think the only difference is that CHttpsession lets you control when to open or close the session and uses object oriented approach, the other way uses Yii's states.

Comment: However, accessing them "everywhere in your code" means "everywhere" is coupled to the global session.  Session access should be minimized and centralized.

Answer (score 3):

To remove the session variable in yii...

Please use this actual format.

```
Yii::app()->session->remove('session_name');
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#remove-detail

Answer (score -1):

```
$session = new \yii\web\Session();

$session->open(); 

$session['account_id'] = $id; 

$session['account_name'] = $name;
```

Comment: code only answers are aweful. Please add some explanation on why/how this works. This is yii2 by the way, not directly related to OP's issue.